# Which topics are left for Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

With all the new `____.stackexchange.com` sites coming up, I wonder if there is some reasoning on which questions **do** belong on `stackoverflow.com`.

The [FAQ site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says a question belongs there if it covers:

1. a specific programming problem
2. a software algorithm
3. software tools commonly used by programmers
4. a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

However as far as I understand for example a "specific programming problem" would belong to

- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), if it is about specific code the person wrote
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), if it is about a design question
- [Software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), if it is about what library to use
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), if it is about user interaction.

Similar sites can be found for the other three points as well.

So my question is: Is there some kind of masterplan what stackoverflow **is** for? Or is it in fact meant to be the site, where everything that is not exactly covered by another site, belongs?

Comment: Code Review doesn't deal with bugs/problems in general. Just code reviews of _working_ code.

Comment: Stack Overflow got its own meta site, this question belongs there, not here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Is that so? I would say my question is not solely about Stack Overflow, but about its relation to the other sides. I don't mind my question to be moved, though.

Comment: Nice find @3ventic, forgot about that post here!

Comment: The fastest metadeduplicators in the west strike again. I think this is a very good question. I'll try raising it again — while expounding on why this is a materially different question — again sometime in the near-intermediate future, but **I totally** get what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Here's the master plan:  StackOverflow is a question/answer site where you can ask and/or answer questions about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, software tools commonly used by programmers, or any other practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.